Need a script to delete a specific cookie in firefox
A webpage often needs it cookie delted in order for me to log in. I would like to create a powershell script to do this in one click, instead of having to manually filter out the cookie by hand every time.
Since I read online that firefox stores all cookies in a single file, I am wondering if this is even possible.
I am on Windows 11, sadly.
I did some online research, but came up empty.

Firefox stores its cookies in the SQLite file %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\<profile_directory>\cookies.sqlite, and the database is quite simple so yeah: it's perfectly doable. I suggest using https://github.com/jhoneill/GetSQL to make a simple script to delete anything you need from the file

Cookie is not a OS specific thing.Its basically browser specific
For example if you are in facebook.com the browser tab for facebook saves some cookie but for lets say reddit.com they save different sets of cookies. So cookies are set on your browser and yes they can be deleted using script
As you did not specify either you are trying to delete them from developer tools or from terminal I will assume you are trying to delete them from  developer tools
Open your firefox window and open console . And again as you have not specify any particular language I will provide a basic code snippet for JS
 document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    document.cookie = cookie.replace(/^ +/, '').replace(/=.*/, '=;expires=' + new Date().toUTCString() + ';path=/');
});

It will set all cookies expiry date to current so its better way to refresh the cookies
More so you can use extension to remove it : Firefox Extenstion

Thanks for your answer. I tagged the question as powrshell, but forgot to mention it in the question itself. Ideally I'd want a .bat or something I can just execute and be done with.
